# Laravel Route with 1 required and Optional unlimited parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have a route defined which calls a test function in TestController.

```
Route::get('/test/{function_name}','TestController@test');
```

This test function calls internally the function that matches the name inside the TestController.

This works for the functions that doesn't need paramters. However certain functions needs paramters and then the route becomes invalid.

```
public function test($function_name)
{
    try
    {
        var_dump($this->$function_name());
        return;
    }
    catch(Exception $ex)
    {
        throw $ex;
    }
}

// This functions get called fine
public function getRecord(){}

// But this functions does not work because i am passing extra paramters in the url which in turns makes the route invalid

public function getRecordByNameAndPrice($name, $price){}
```

So is there any way that i can defined a route in such a way that it should contain 1 parameter but should also allow N number of extra parameters so that i can call those functions that needs paramters.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `where` method to allow your rest to contain slashes:

```php
Route::get('test/{func}/{rest?}', 'TestController@test')->where('rest', '.*');
```

Then use `$request->segments()` to get them all as separate values:

```php
public function test($method, Request $request)
{
    $params = array_slice($request->segments(), 2);

    return call_user_func_array([$this, $method], $params);
}
```

Don't forget to `use Illuminate\Http\Request` up top.

Comment: Getting failed respone

Comment: Buy removing `?` Now when i hit the url that contains the function with no paramter it says : `page doesn't exists` and when i call the function with parameters it fails with no error message

Comment: @RaheelKhan - what does `Getting failed respone` mean? You have to provide more details.

Comment: Yeah sorry i was not seeing at logs. Here is the error
`Argument 2 passed to TestController::test() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, none given' in /var/www/html/hubwire_api/app/controllers/TestController.php:8`

Comment: @RaheelKhan - Didn't realize you were still stuck on Laravel 4. Remove that second argument, and use the facade instead: `Request::segments()`

Comment: Cool works. But `?` is required otherwise it is not working in case of no extra parameters. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

let's say your url is
    `/products?id=999&format=json&apikey=123456`
and define your route like this

```
Route::get('/prodcuts',function(){
    return Request::all();
})
//  output

{"id":"999","format":"json","apikey"=>"123456"}
```

Comment: Yes but the part where i said that it should allow optional paramters in the url is missing in your answer

Comment: @RaheelKhan can you show me a url example with optional parameters you want to include